# Cannot call titleForRow method UIPickerView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

in my viewcontroller class i have a property `UIViewPicker` myPicker. in didSelectRow method (also implemented by the UIPicker delegate. I try the following

```
NSString* temp = [self.myPicker titleForRow:1 inComponent:0].
```

However it says that the method is not found and says that return type defaults to "id".

What am i doing wrong????`

Comment: thats because there is no such method available in ios sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"it says that the method is not found" because this a delegate method for UIPickerViewDelegate. Check the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html). Delegate methods are implemented, NOT called! Delegates are like listeners and their methods need to be implemented by the class that implements the delegates. The methods are called automatically and the order in which they are called is predefined. You only have to know the conditions under which they are called.

You can always create your own methods as long as they are different from the delegate methods.

Comment: i see. makes sense actually, since it works if i call `NSString* temp = [self pickerView:self.myPicker titleForRow:1 forComponent:0];
` since it is called by a class that implements it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a delegate method which you can use to set particular titles for rows. I don't believe you can call it via an instance like this. You'll need to implement this method separately in your current controller (which should implement the UIPickerViewDelegate) and then work from there.

e.g.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (row==1)
    return @"Title 1";

if (row==2)
    return @"Title 2";

return @"Default Title";
```

}

Comment: i have done this. im trying to call this method from didSelectRow (another method i implemented from the UIPickerViewDelegate)

Comment: Just to understand what you're doing here, I assume you're trying to get the title of the row that was selected?

Comment: yes. in the didSelectMethod i want to get the title of the row that was selected so i can display it in a label somewhere

Comment: I dont believe there is a way to directly access the row and its title as you need. The general way this works is that since YOU will be setting the titles in some way (say from an array, using the above method), in the didSelectRow method, we would use the index of the row on that array (basically the same dataSource) to get the title.

Answer (score 1):

try the following statement

```
NSString* temp = [self pickerView:self.myPicker titleForRow:1 forComponent:0];
```

I think,it will solve your problem.

Thanks

Satya

Comment: @robin why not? this actually compiles and does what i wanted to do. it still puzzles me that it cant be called the other way

Comment: @robin: you are implementing that delegate method in your class. so you can use that method, with that class object.

Comment: The delegate methods are called automatically when the object needs some work to be done. If you call it by your self then it will have some pretty bad results.

Comment: @robin : In my experience I didn't get any bad results, by calling like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
NSString* temp = [pickerView titleForRow:1 inComponent:0];
```

inside the mentioned method.

Comment: note sure how thats any different. i realized i was missing a bracket in my question so i fixed it